# How to set Path Fill in a style in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, fill, datatrigger

So I have this code that creates a blue circle, and I am trying to make it change color based on the parameter Color, which is bound (this works, as it will react correctly if I edit something other than Fill) in the provided example. The problem here is the innermost line, `<Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red">`. It does not make the path's fill red. Also worth mentioning is that this circle is also part of a DataTemplate, where some of the objects needs a blue ring, and others red.

```
<Path Fill="Blue" Grid.Column="1">
  <Path.Data>
    <EllipseGeometry Center="0,0" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" />
  </Path.Data>
  <Path.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="Red">
          <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Path.Style>
</Path>
```

Comment: Replace `Fill="Blue"` by a Style Setter. That said, if the type of the Color property is System.Windows.Media.Color, you may alternatively set the Path's Fill to a SolidColorBrush with `Color="{Binding Color}"`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!